# Question on associative property of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the proof of

> A ∩ (B - C) = (A ∩ B) - (A ∩ C)

Most of the proofs I have seen involve the following steps:

> i) Let x be an arbitrary element of A ∩ (B - C)
>
> ii) ⇒ x ∈ A and x ∈ (B - C)
>
> iii) ⇒ x ∈ A and x ∈ B, but x ∉ C
>
> iv) ⇒ x ∈ (A ∩ B), but x ∉ (A ∩ C)
>
> The proof is continued further.

I have problem in Part iii and iv. How did we reach part iv from iii. According to me we should have used the associative law that A ∩ (B ∩ C)=(A ∩ B) ∩ C .

According to me the following steps should be taken

> x ∈ A and x ∈ B, but x ∉ C
>
> x ∈ A and x ∈ B, and x ∉ C
>
> x ∈ (A ∩ B) and x ∉ C
>
> x ∈ (A ∩ B) and x ∈ C'
>
> x ∈ (A ∩ B)∩ C'
>
> x ∈ (A ∩ B)- C
>
> This leads to nowhere

Please tell me why is part iv the correct step after iii and not what I suppose.

Thank you

Comment: There is a mistake in your steps: you went from $x \in A \cap B$ and $x \not\in C$ to $x \in A \cap B$ and $x \in C$. That is a contradiction because $x$ wasn't an element of $C$ and then somehow it became an element of $C$ in the next step - how is that possible?

Comment: Anyways, what the proof did in going from (iii) to (iv) was to apply this reasoning by contraposition: if $x \in A \cap C$ then $x \in C$; therefore by the contrapositive if $x \not\in C$, then $x \not\in A \cap C$.

Comment: @ ZeroXLR  In the next step I have written x∈ A∩B and x∈ C'. There is a "dash(')" above C which is the set of all elements not in C. But thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct set algebra proof.

$A \cap (B - C) = A \cap B \cap C^c =  $
$(A \cap B \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap B \cap C^c) =  
A \cap B \cap (A^c \cup C^c) =$
$A \cap B \cap (A \cap C)^c = A \cap B - (A \cap C)
$

Comment: Sir please explain me how you have simplified A ∩ B ∩ C^c to A∩ B∩ (A^c∪C^c ).

Comment: @AshokSharma Distributivity.  See edit.

Comment: +1 I'd add $X\setminus Y = X\cap Y^c$ at the beginning, just for completeness.

Comment: @ William Elliot I still cannot understand how you got                                             A ∩ B ∩ C^c = (A ∩ B ∩ A^c)∪(A ∩ B∩ C^c)

Comment: @AshokSharma.  A ∩ B ∩ A^c is empty.

Comment: May be it will be more obvious for unexperienced readers if you added an intermediate step with $\emptyset  \cup (A \cap B \cap C^c)$ in the second line.

Answer (score 0):

> iii)  x ∈ A and x ∈ B, but x ∉ C
>   iv) ⇒ x ∈ (A ∩ B), but x ∉ (A ∩ C)

I understand the first part about `(A ∩ B)` is obvious. Let's look at the second one then.

As (iii) states, $x$ does not belong to $C$.
Hence it also does not belong to the part of $C$, which $C$ shares with $A$.
That is, $A\cap C$.
So we have (iv): `x ∉ (A ∩ C)`.